# Ordering of bundles for which the axioms of transitivity, continuity, strong monotonicity and convexity are valid

Tags: preferences

Let there be two bundles which are obtained from the sequences $x^n = (x_1,x_2)= \left( 2 + \frac{1}{n},5 \right)$ and $y^n = (y_1,y_2) = \left(4 + \frac{2}{n}, 5 \right)$. Is it possible to obtain an ordering of the bundles such that the axioms of transitivity, continuity, strong monotonicity and convexity are respected?

My attempt:

Suppose the preference relation $\succsim$ is lexicographic.

It can be seen that $$4 + \frac{2}{n} > 2 + \frac{1}{n}, \,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{R}_+ $$
Furthermore, at the limit: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} y^n = 4 > 2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n$$

which means, given that $\succsim$ is lexicographic, that $y \succ x, \forall n \in [1,\infty)$, even at the limit. Therefore, $\succsim$ is continuous.

Furthermore, since $y_1 > x_1, \forall n \in [1,\infty)$, $y_2=x_2, \forall n \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $y \succ x$, $\succsim$ is also strongly monotonic.

Let $z^n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n},5\right)$. In an analogous manner, since $\succsim$ is lexicographic, $x^n \succ z^n$ and $y^n \succ z^n$ and thus $\succsim$ is also transitive.

Now, let $k^n = \left( 2 + \frac{1}{n}, 4 \right)$ and $$ \begin{align}\tau &= \lambda \cdot x^n + (1-\lambda) \cdot y^n, \lambda \in (0,1) \\ &= \left(4-2\lambda + \frac{2}{n} -\frac{\lambda}{n}, 5 \right) \end{align} $$

Since $x^n \succsim z^n$ and $y^n \succsim z^n$, in order for $\succsim$ to be strictly convex we must have $\tau \succ k^n$, which implies that:

$$ 4-2\lambda + \frac{2}{n} - \frac{\lambda}{n} > 2 + \frac{1}{n} \therefore  2 \cdot (1-\lambda) > -\frac{1}{n} \cdot (1-\lambda) \therefore 2 > -\frac{1}{n} $$

which is true for all $n \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Thus, the ordering found when considering $\succsim$ to be a lexicographic preference relation is transitive, continuous, strongly monotonic, and convex (strictly convex).

Is my answer correct?

Comment: I think that the ground set on which your relation has to satisfy this conditions is: $X = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n \cup \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} y_n$. NB:  $z_n \notin X \forall n  \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Thanks for the input, @GradaGukovic! So if I let $z^n = (2,5)$ instead, it would be correct, right? Because then $z^n \in X, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and also $x^n \succsim z^n$ and $y^n \succsim z^n$, even at the limits.